# Trouble with Hamachi - can't ping other machine

Tags: hamachi

I'm just setting up Hamachi, but having some trouble.
I have a Hamachi instance running on my Linux machine at home and I'm trying to connect to the Samba share on it via my Windows laptop.  The Hamachi UI on my laptop shows a 5.x.x.x IP address with a blue star next to it.  It also shows a 5.x.x.x IP address for my Linux machine with a green star next to it.
I can't access any of the network services or SSH to my Linux machine.  If I try pinging it from the Hamachi UI that also fails.  Is it expected that the pinging would fail since I don't have a web server running on my Linux machine?  What else can I do to troubleshoot?
Could I be having problems because I'm behind a firewall at my workplace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the features of Hamachi is that is can supposedly traverse firewalls.  However, I have not found connecting from a Windows machine to a Linux machine using Hamachi to be reliable in any circumstance.  See the numerous issues and complaints on the Hamachi Linux forum at https://forums.hamachi.cc/

Hamachi, since being acquired by LogMeIn, has shown abysmal consideration to Linux users. I find the product unreliable when Linux machines are part of my hamachi network.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably the firewall.  Something you can try is going to a starbucks or something with free wireless and see if you can connect then.

Answer (score 0):

Ping service is not related to HTTP (web) service. In fact, ping is even built into kernel. You should try joining other networks and pinging one of the machines on those nets: if you succeed, then it's probably not the firewall.

I've had similar issues with Linux Hamachi; it took a chunk of fiddling to get it to work, and a truckload of luck to get it to work. I'd say you should examine your Linux Hamachi setup, especially if it turns out that Windows-to-Windows connections work.

Answer (score 0):

When I have problems like that , the connection usually shows up as a different colored dot (not green).   What are you seeing, as far as the colored dot (assuming your using the unmanaged free version of Hamachi2) ?    The ONLY circumstance where I have ever had a problem with Hamachi is behind a PIX firewall that "i assume" was blocking UDP or something.  When that occurs the "chat" and "ping" function of Hamachi still works but you just cant get the connection via RDP nor via file sharing.